# How to reduce lag on a server?

Tags: linux, thin-client

I have an application client that connects to our server. Our customers download it and use, but some of them are getting bad lag spikes.

Server seems to be running pretty fine, but the problem stills.

I'm getting myself an average of 380ms on ping tests.
While I'm using the application client I experience no lags at all.

What could I check?
What could I do to improve my customers experience?

I have read somewhere I have to find some way to reduce the latency, is that true?
If it is, how to do that?

Comment: the usual: more bandwidth and more RAM. also, moving the server to a location nearer to where most of your costumers reside might be a good choice.

Comment: Oh...I see, I'll check what can be done, thank you.